# Does the standard log normal distribution have a heavy right tail?

Tags: normal-distribution

I read about heavy right tail and I saw that a distribution is said to have a heavy right tail if its tail probabilities vanish slower than any exponential
$$\forall t>0,\,\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{tx}P(X>x)=+\infty$$.

I also saw that the normal distribution does not have right tail .
Im not sure about the log normal distribution.

Does the standard log normal distribution have a heavy right tail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I answered you [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988774/does-the-standard-normal-distribution-have-a-heavy-right-tail/3988823#3988823) a distribution of a random variable $X$ is called heavy right tailed iff the moment generating function $M_X(t)$ is infinite for all $t>0$. So you either try to calculate the integrals
$$\mathbb E e^{tX}
$$
or you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Characteristic_function_and_moment_generating_function) to read that the integrals do not converge.